# Is it possible to stream a response directly to another POST request in c#

Tags: c#, httprequest

I would like to POST the data from a large file downloaded from a url.  Currently I am doing this by first saving the file locally, and then posting that file's data to another Api.

Is it possible to read from the file download request, and post to the second request without first having to save the file to disk?

Answer (score 0):

Saving to disk first is not necessary but depending on the size of the file you may have problems.   All you do is send a byte array but depending on the size you may have issues and saving to disk first may be more manageable.